# Storing station data in netcdf and plotting on map using R. Station wise with location as attributes or all grid points?

Tags: r, netcdf, select-by-location

I have around 100 stations of data spread over around 60 deg lon x 50 deg lon which I want to save as a netcdf using R. Do I have to make a netcdf with all grid points with non-stations being NAN or can I just store the stations (with positions) as netcdf and plot lon/lat wise when needed on a map? 
I need to make a NETCDF so that I can plot this dataset using other software like GRADS or compare with topography etc.

Comment: Why do you want to save it as a netcdf? If it is just station data (x,y,m) then another file format might be better.

Comment: netcdf so that I can plot using other plotters such as grads if required.

Comment: if you want to compare data sampled at points across an area defined by a grid you need to interpolate your sampled points to the grid first.

Comment: I know that and that's doable

Comment: Okay, so does my answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have netCDF support in your `rgdal` package you can do this.

First, some test data:

```
> library(sp)
> library(rgdal)
> library(raster)
> pts = data.frame(x=runif(50),y=runif(50),z1=rnorm(50),z2=rnorm(50))
> coordinates(pts)=~x+y
> projection(pts)="+init=epsg:4326"
```

Then use something like this:

```
> writeOGR(pts,"/tmp/test.nc",layer="pts", driver="netCDF")
```

This is not a grid, it is the raw x,y,z1,z2 data points.

```
> library(ncdf4)
> nc = nc_open("/tmp/test.nc")
> print(nc)
```

will show you the structure of the ncdf file.

Comment: This will solve the problem for plotting in R as lat, lon are separate variables being stored. But this file is not plottable in other software like GRADS.

Answer (score 0):

A netcdf file do not have to be a grid. This can be a list of positions not regularly spread. You will have a vector of longitude, a vector of latitude and a vector of observations.
To plot it in R, you will need to use library `ncdf4` for instance and extract vars of lat, lon and obs to create a spatial object to be plotted.

Comment: But can I plot Lat, lon, time and value (in color) in a 4-d plot from an ungridded netcdf?